# Find an open set whose preimage is not open for $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f(0)=0, f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ otherwise in $\mathbb{R}$

Find an open set whose preimage is not open.

I think I need an open set not including $0$.

Comment: I think you need a small, open set specifically _including_ $0$, like $(-0.1,0.1)$.

Comment: What is the preimage?

Comment: If y is close to zero and cos (1/x) = y is close to zero than 1/x is close to pi/2 so preimage is a set close to 2/pi union with 0.  Not open.

Comment: @Metric spaces. The preimage of a set $S$ for a function $ F$ is $F^{-1}S=\{x :F(x)\in S\}.$

Answer (score 2):

The inverse image of the open interval $I=(-1/2,1/2)$ of $0$ is not open. It contains $0$ but does not contain an interval $0\in J$ such that $f(J)\subset I$, since $1/(2\pi n)$ converges towards $0$ and $f(1/(2\pi n))=1$.

Comment: @Arthur : How so?  The inverse image of this set is $\{ x\in\mathbb R : f(x) \in (-1/2,1/2) \}$.  That's what this is. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy My comment was left over from before this answer was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{\pi/2 + k\pi\}$

$\cos^{-1}((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = \cup (\pi/2 + k\pi-\delta, \pi/2 + k\pi+\gamma)$ for some $\delta,\gamma$.  If we choose $\epsilon$ small enough, these intervals will be disjoint and not include $0$.

Let $g(x) = \cos(1/x)$ then $g^{-1}((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = \cup ({1 \over \pi/2 + k\pi-\delta},{1 \over  \pi/2 + k\pi+\gamma})$ which can be made disjoint and not containing 0.  This is an open set.

Thus if $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$ but equals $g(x)$ otherwise

The $f^{-1}((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = \cup ({1 \over \pi/2 + k\pi-\delta},{1 \over  \pi/2 + k\pi+\gamma}) \cup \{0\}$ which is not an open set.